# How to modify Activity's attribute in manifest with gradle task?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have two android gradle project *A* and *B*. Both project have the same aar library called *lib*. The lib has an acitivity called *Act*.

I use url scheme to jump into the *Act*.But each time i jump from *A* or *B*. The system want me to choose which app to accept the action.

My idea is that if i can change the *lib*'s scheme in different project. The problem should be gone.

So my question is , which gradle task should i use to change the same activity's scheme ? how to deal with it ? or if any better idea please tell me, thanks !